# How to check if a word in a key exists in a JSON object in java?

Tags: java, json

Let's assume I have the following JSON file:

```
{
  "id1" : "User",
  "id2" : "Admin"
  "gender" : "Male"
}
```

If I want to check if a JSONObject has a key containing the string 'id', how would I accomplish this? When I try doing something like:

```
for(JsonElement e : json.getAsJsonObject().get("accounts").getAsJsonArray()){
JsonObject json = e.getAsJsonObject();
    if(json.has("id")){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to work. I assume that this is because the key names in the JSON are not strictly named "id" rather "id1" and "id2".

Comment: What JSON library are you using? You need to iterate over the keys, then check the string

Comment: do you want to check if a key starts with "id"?

Comment: @Janar Yes I do.

Comment: @cricket_007 For this example, my code will be iterating through each key

Comment: What code? Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: @cricket_007 I updated my question to include more of the code if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have used json-simple1.1.jar for this.

```
JSONParser parser= new JSONParser();
        try{
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("E://test.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject =  (JSONObject) obj;

            Iterator iterator = jsonObject.keySet().iterator();

            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                if(String.valueOf(iterator.next()).startsWith("id")){

                    System.out.println("Present");
                }
            }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Logging error message
        }
```

Comment: The question is how do you get `key`?

Answer (score 0):

**i know these method to find key**

```
import org.json.JSONObject;



        JSONObject object = new JSONObject("your json");
        setString(object.keySet());
        list(object.keys());
        System.out.println(object.keySet().contains("id1")); // boolean will be return if your json has id1 or id2 and you are looking for id it will return false

public void setString(Set<String> list)
    {
        for(String s1:list)
        {
            if(s1.contains("id"))
            {
                System.out.println("Contains");
            }
        }
    }

    public void list(Iterator<String> list)
    {
        while(list.hasNext())
        {
            if(list.next().contains("id"))
            {
                System.out.println("Contains");

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If using `Java 8` or later: Get `JsonObject` fields as entry set and loop like

```
String json = "{ \"id1\" : \"User\", \"id2\" : \"Admin\"," 
          + " \"gender\" : \"Male\" }";
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jo = jp.parse(new StringReader(json)).getAsJsonObject();
jo.entrySet().forEach( e -> {
   if(e.getKey().startsWith("id")) // or contains("id")
      log.info("has key: {}", e.getKey()); ;
});
```

output is like

> 2017-12-16 20:07:43.779 INFO  org.example.ExampleJUnitTTest:52  - has key: id1
>   2017-12-16 20:07:43.785 INFO  org.example.ExampleJUnitTTest:52  - has key: id2